# SAMLResponse contains \r\n - why? what's best way to get rid of it?

Tags: objective-c, newline, saml

We read it from a POST the identity provider does, but after converting it to base64 from the raw post, the response has \r\n

this happens with OneLogin, but not with ADFS.

we decided to just replace the \r\n with nothing, and it works - but it seems like a weird solution.

i havent found much information about \r\n in SAMLResponses and how to properly handle them.

Any insights?

thanks